# JavaScript Object and Primitive

Tags: javascript, prototype

Please I want someone to explain the code below for me:

```
 var f = new Number(44);

 f.name = "Yusuf";
 f.hello = function() {
   console.log("Hello");
 };

 console.log(typeof f);

 f.hello();

 console.log(f.name);
 console.log(f.toString() + "good");
 console.log(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty(name));
 console.log(f.hasOwnProperty(hello));
 console.log(f.length);
```

When I check the variable type. Object gets return and I am sure this is because of the Number object constructor call function. I added two properties, one a member and a method and when I call them , it work but when I used hasOwnProperty(), false is return for the member key and undefined for the method key.

Why is it so?

where are the methods going to if the hasOwnProperty doesn't work as usual when it is supposed to when I am actually checking the property on the containing object.?

I checked Number and object object and they all return false.

Comment: you have to pass strings, not references. `name` -> `"name"`, `hello` -> `"hello"` ...

Comment: Get familiar with how javascript works, because it seems you are not, look at the signature of Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Comment: You have wrong idea about how prototypes work. Prototype is actually created when you write a function. And you are trying to access "Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty(name)" when you have nothing to do with it. There is no any relationship between Object's prototype and your f object's prototype.

Answer (score 0):

The [`hasOwnProperty` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) takes the property key as a string:

```
console.log(Number.prototype.hasOwnProperty("name"));
console.log(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(f, "name"));
console.log(f.hasOwnProperty("name"));
console.log(f.hasOwnProperty("hello"));
```

I recommend to always [`"use strict"` mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) so that you get exceptions when you try to use undeclared variables.